# Wrapping a Constructor in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vba

I am working on an API to be compatible with VBA. The API is written in C#, Now after few changes to the source code, I am able to add the reference in VBA. However, the API has a base class with parameterized constructors and Methods. How do I wrap or access the object from VBA. Below is the sample Code.

```
public class SmartApi : ISmartApi
{
    protected string USER = "USER", SourceID = "WEB", PrivateKey = "";
    static string ClientPublicIP = "", ClientLocalIP = "", MACAddress = "";

    //protected string APIURL = "https://openapisuat.angelbroking.com";
    protected string APIURL = "https://apiconnect.angelbroking.com"; //prod endpoint

    AngelToken Token { get; set; }

    /*Constructors*/
    public SmartApi(string _PrivateKey)
    {
        PrivateKey = _PrivateKey;

        ClientPublicIP = Helpers.GetPublicIPAddress();
        if (ClientPublicIP == "")
            ClientPublicIP = Helpers.GetPublicIPAddress();

        if (ClientPublicIP == "")
            ClientPublicIP = "106.193.147.98";

        ClientLocalIP = Helpers.GetLocalIPAddress();

        if (ClientLocalIP == "")
            ClientLocalIP = "127.0.0.1";

        if (Helpers.GetMacAddress() != null)
            MACAddress = Helpers.GetMacAddress().ToString();
        else
            MACAddress = "fe80::216e:6507:4b90:3719";
    }
    
    public SmartApi(string _PrivateKey, string _jwtToken = "", string _refreshToken = "")
    {
        PrivateKey = _PrivateKey;

        this.Token = new AngelToken();
        this.Token.jwtToken = _jwtToken;
        this.Token.refreshToken = _refreshToken;
        this.Token.feedToken = "";

        ClientPublicIP = Helpers.GetPublicIPAddress();
        if (ClientPublicIP == "")
            ClientPublicIP = Helpers.GetPublicIPAddress();

        if (ClientPublicIP == "")
            ClientPublicIP = "106.193.147.98";

        ClientLocalIP = Helpers.GetLocalIPAddress();

        if (ClientLocalIP == "")
            ClientLocalIP = "127.0.0.1";

        if (Helpers.GetMacAddress() != null)
            MACAddress = Helpers.GetMacAddress().ToString();
        else
            MACAddress = "fe80::216e:6507:4b90:3719";
    }
    //other methods below
}
```

I need to create objects for smartapi and pass arguments from VBA. Also the c# project has reference to Newtonsoft.Json file. Do I need to import to VBA module for the solution to work.

Comment: Which class in the code has base class constructor with parameters?

Comment: Create a separate com visible "factory" class that returns a new instance of the SmartApi class, then you can simply `dim f as new SmartApiFactory() / set SmartApi = f.CreateSmartApi( ctor args here )`

Comment: If the C# project privately uses Newtonsoft.Json then no, you dont need to make VBA aware of that fact for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the replies   @AlexK. I am still a learner, can u just guide me on how to create factory class that returns smartapi instance, just the design so that I can implement in the thirdparty code. Chetan-SmartApi Class itself is the base class

Comment: @Chetan Could you please provide some example on Alex's workaround